# How to insert data in to multiple table using django orm

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

i have created 2 table, ie table1 and table2 i want to insert data in to both tables using django ORM , how can i achieve it

models.py

```py
class Table1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)

class Table2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
```

views.py

```py
class Test(ListAPIView):
    def get(self,request):
        obj1 = Table1(name="jasir")
        obj2 = Table2(name="shibin")

        obj1.save()
        obj2.save()

        return Response(True)
```

im saving like this but i want to save it using single save() instance is there any possiblity 
the equivalent sql query i found is

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   INSERT INTO Table1 (name) VALUES ('jasir')
   INSERT INTO Table2 (name) VALUES ('shibin')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

how to do the same with django ORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the saves atomic like this:

```
with django.db.transaction.atomic():
    obj1.save()
    obj2.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Django's `transcation.atomic` context-manager to do that

Refer to:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

```
with transaction.atomic():
        # This code executes inside a transaction.
        obj1 = Table1(name="jasir")
        obj2 = Table2(name="shibin")

        obj1.save()
        obj2.save()
```